# python function using celery apply_sync, issue with parsing args

Tags: python, django-celery

I have a celery app that's supposed to run a background process, here's what it looks like

```
task = render_image.apply_async(kwargs={
    'image': image,
    'pos': (x, y),
    'deviation': variance,
    'switch': switch_color,
    'perspective': keep_perspective,
    'colors': colors,
    'new_color': new_color,
    'color': colour,
    'area_id': area_id,
    'cls_id': cls_id,
    'grayscale': grayscale,
    'unique_processing_id': unique_processing_id, #line number 394
})
```

added 394 for the line number

this calls a function render_image which is linked to the celery app and looks like this

```
from revamp.celery import app

@app.task(bind=True)
def render_image(image, pos, deviation, switch, perspective, colors, new_color, color, area_id, cls_id, grayscale, unique_processing_id):
    ...
```

on running this I get this error

```
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/views.py", line 394, in start_render_part
    'unique_processing_id': unique_processing_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 518, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: render_image() got multiple values for keyword argument 'image'
```

decided I can simplify it more to this

```
    task = render_image.apply_async(image, (x, y), variance, switch_color, keep_perspective, colors, new_color, colour, area_id, cls_id, grayscale, unique_processing_id)
```

then I got this error

```
Internal Server Error: /start-render-part
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/handler.py", line 243, in process_exception_by_middleware
    return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/views.py", line 382, in start_render_part
    task = render_image.apply_async(image, (x, y), variance, switch_color, keep_perspective, colors, new_color, colour, area_id, cls_id, grayscale, unique_processing_id)
TypeError: apply_async() takes at most 8 arguments (13 given)
```

noted that since this is going through `apply_async` docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html should have it more like this

```
task = render_image.apply_async(args={
    'image': image,
    'pos': (x, y),
    'deviation': variance,
    'switch': switch_color,
    'perspective': keep_perspective,
    'colors': colors,
    'new_color': new_color,
    'color': colour,
    'area_id': area_id,
    'cls_id': cls_id,
    'grayscale': grayscale,
    'unique_processing_id': unique_processing_id,
})
```

but I get a one missing paramater error likely self

```
Internal Server Error: /start-render-part
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/handler.py", line 243, in process_exception_by_middleware
    return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/views.py", line 394, in start_render_part
    'unique_processing_id': unique_processing_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 518, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: render_image() takes exactly 12 arguments (13 given)
```

this makes me assume then render_image needs a "self" argument.

Comment: below my solution seems OK or not ??,if you struggle let me know

Comment: fixed it by adding self to render_image and keeping to kwargs but thanks

Comment: my answer seems okay for you

Comment: possibly could work wouldn't know without changing the code

Answer (score 0):

Here the defination

> args (Tuple) – positional arguments passed on to the task
>
> kwargs (Dict) – keyword arguments passed on to the task.

if you need pass the dict value use kwargs,if you need pass args that can accept tuple or list

```
render_image.apply_async(args=[
                          image,
                          (x, y),
                          variance,
                          switch_color,
                          keep_perspective,
                          colors,
                          new_color,
                          area_id,
                          cls_id,
                          grayscaleunique_processing_id
                        ])
```

If you know more refer the docs [apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html) function

Answer (score 0):

If you decorate your task with `@app.task(bind=True)`, then the first argument passed to the task will be `self`.

From the [Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.2.6/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks):

> A task being bound means the first argument to the task will always be the task instance (self), just like Python bound methods:

So add self as the first argument to your task function `render_image`.